# How to reduce the execution time in stored procedure using mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

i am working on asp.net3.5 and mysql, now my problem is search page enter the text click the search button fetch the records and bind the gridview , **it taking more time(like 1min) but i can reduce the execution time** how it possible in front end or back end please give me any idea about that.

thanking u
hemanth

Comment: How many records are you pulling from the database?

Comment: Can you provide source to your stored procedure... probably its a matter of optimizing a query... and if in a loop within a stored procedure, that might be able to be combined into a single query vs loop/repeated queries to return result sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For tuning the performance of a SP we need to know how much resources 
it is using and how much time it takes in execution.

1) Look the queries performence using Execution Plan. After 
find the Queries, just check the Index(for table used in 
query) and look the join conditions between tables in the 
query. - This is way we need to approch to tune the SP.

2) we need to use tablename with (nolock) in our select 
statements so that it does not create delay if other person 
is updating the table at the same time it will show last 
updated table recordset

3) if we dont need that much the database server to return 
the number of records affected after executing any dml 
statements which actually reduces the performance ,we can 
use set nocount on -set nocount off before and after 
writing the sql query,

4) we can create lesser join statements if we can use 
subqueries

Answer (score 0):

- Try getting lesser values on front end.
- Try getting them using AJAX which are [Ajax benifit](http://blog.httpwatch.com/2008/04/18/the-performance-benefits-of-ajax/)
- Try optimizing your [SQL QUERY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/02/16/sql-server-stored-procedure-optimization-tips-best-practices/)

[This link will guide how Store Procedure Reduces Time](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.dc.doc/dc/c_spbenefits.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Without any sample code, there's not much we can work on. But since you asked for *ideas*...

I can think of two possible reasons why your page loads slow:

1. SQL side of things - Teez basically said what needs to be said.
2. Display of results - How are you binding to the gridview? Are there extra database calls when you're binding? Are you performing pagination? How?

Answer (score 0):

You can improve performance by optimizing your query.

- Select only `relevant columns` instead of `select *`
- Use Join if large number of records are there other wise use sub query (For such cases)

[Query Optimization](http://hackmysql.com/documents)